# How do i replace letters with underscores but let the spaces stay in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, javascript-objects

i am trying to replace the letters i get from the word with underscores but if there is any spaces in that word i do not want to replace it. im not sure how to do it. the current code i am using is this
answerArray = []
function randomWord() {

```
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        answerArray[i] = "_"
        answer.innerHTML = answerArray.join(" ")
    }
}
```

i've tried to look around in stackoverflow with my question but no one has it. someones suggested this

```
word.replace(/\w/gi, '_')
```

but it isnt working as i want.

You can check out the code here https://codepen.io/NoNameYet04/pen/OJxKYeV
i have for the test change the word in "programming language" to "test test" so you can test it out

Comment: *"but it isnt working as i want."*: can you provide details? For which input did it not create the desired output, and what should it have given instead? NB: although links can be interesting as background information, be aware that any essential information, needed to understand the question, must not be behind a link.

Comment: @trincot my bad. i meant that after that code the word should be "TEST TEST" and not "TEST_TEST"

Comment: I don't understand. If you expect "TEST TEST", then where are the underscores? No replacement at all? NB: that solution does not put an underscore as in "TEST_TEST". Are you sure you are talking about that solution? It would be better that you provide in your question a little piece of code that reproduces this problem when using the `replace` solution.

Comment: @trinot word should be with 8 underscores for that example but i get 9 because of the space. and i want to remove the space underscore with for example a regular space.

Comment: You didn't update your question... I cannot reproduce your problem. The `replace` function returns the expected result for "TEST TEST". The space is not altered. So if you still believe you have the problem, prove it by providing your script with sample input, so we can run it and reproduce your problem. I am voting to close this question now.

Comment: @trincot you can close the question now i got the answer

Comment: An answer can be closed when you either post the answer, or mark the correct answer as accepted. If however, you made a mistake, and the question was actually based on an error at your side, then just delete the question.

Comment: @trincot no it wasnt a mistake. everyone who posted an answer did it right and it worked

Comment: Then you *did* make a mistake, because one of the answers uses the code you mentioned (see also my above comments): `word.replace(/\w/g, "_");` just works. BTW, your answers to above comments are very confusing. Just read it yourself from top to bottom.

Comment: except him though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomWord() {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = word[i] == " " ? "&nbsp;" : "_"; // <==
    console.log(answerArray[i]);
    answer.innerHTML = answerArray.join(" ")
  }
}
```

Explanation: Is the current character you're iterating a space in the word? If yes we insert a space (in this case an HTML space), if not we just insert an underscore.

Also, don't forget to change the assignment of the variable **remainingLetters** in your `category()` function so you're ignoring the space.

```
function category(type) {
  /* ... */
  remainingLetters = word.replace(/ /g, "").length;
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: thats work but what is the word also have an "-" or " ' ", is it a way to remove them and maybe put a space instead

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's a space using an if statement like this:

```
if (word[i] !== ' '){
   answerArray[i] = '_';
}
else {
    answerArray[i] = ' ';
}
```

Comment: that works too but what is the word also have an "-" or " ' ", is it a way to remove them or maybe put a space instead

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick example below. With problems like this it's always better to try to break it down into small logical steps.

- Go through each character
- If it's a space then leave it
- If it's not then replace with an _

  ```
  function randomWord(word) {
        let ret = ""; // return string

        for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) { // go through each character
            if(word[i] !== " "){ // if it's not a space then replace it
              ret += "_";
            } else if (word[i] === " "){ // if it's a space then we add to the return string
              ret += " ";
            }

        }
        return ret; //return or answer.innerHTML = ret;
  ```

  }

Call using:
randomWord("hello there");

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this one by `split` the string to array and `replace` the word and finally `join` back.

The output for `programming language` will be `___________ ________`

If you want to trigger the space between each character, use `replace(/\w/g, '_ ')` instead of `replace(/\w/g, '_')`

```js
let word = 'programming language'
let answerArray = []
let newword = word.split(' ').forEach(i => {
  answerArray.push(i.replace(/\w/g, '_ '))
})
// answer.innerHTML = answerArray.join(" ")
console.log(answerArray.join(" "))
```